# Help with wheel lock

Tags: chevrolet, wheels, camaro

I have a 2011 rs Chevy camaro and I do not have the wheel lock key for the wheel lock. The wheel lock has 7 spline but are uneven and I can't find it anywhere.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqECM.jpg]

Answer (score 4):

To remove it, the easiest way I've seen is to get a sacrificial socket of the proper size (just a bit smaller than the lug) and drive it onto the wheel lock using a hammer. If done correctly, you can then use a breaker bar to get it off of there. You can possibly drive the lock out of your socket, but it's going to take a vice and a good swing of the hammer. Yes, you'll no longer be able to use the lock, but if you don't have the key in the first place, it's about the easiest way to get them off short of destroying the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

The official dealer will be able to sell you the correct replacement, owners are well-known for loosing them.

You can sometimes find them on the bay of fleas, including complete sets.

I have removed them from my car as they were a well-known failure point even if you had the correct key.

Answer (score 0):

I would inquire at your shop/dealer as to whether they have the appropriate tool.  If they do, ask them to take the locking lug off.  Then buy a non-locking lug.

It would be OK to drive around for a couple of days while you get a replacement lug.  Just no road rallies.